# Puppeteer - Can't set cookies? ("is missing the following properties from type 'CookieParam': name, value")

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-scraping, cookies, puppeteer

my cookie variable:

```js
const cookies = [{
    domain: ".apollo.io",
    expirationDate: 1703861523,
    hostOnly: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    name: "__hssc",
    path: "/",
    sameSite: "lax",
    secure: false,
    session: false,
    storeId: "0",
    value: "21978340.1.170385",
    id: 1,
  },
```

me calling setCookie from puppeteer:

```js
await page.setCookie(cookies);
```

the error message that it gives me:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ domain: string; expirationDate: number; hostOnly: boolean; httpOnly: boolean; name: string; path: string; sameSite: string; secure: boolean; session: boolean; storeId: string; value: string; id: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CookieParam'.
  Type '{ domain: string; expirationDate: number; hostOnly: boolean; httpOnly: boolean; name: string; path: string; sameSite: string; secure: boolean; session: boolean; storeId: string; value: string; id: number; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'CookieParam': name, value
```

As you can see, name and value are not missing... I went one-by-one and nothing seems to differ in both...

I've tried changing types, googling "CookieParams" type, and putting quotes on the cookie keys, etc for quite some time

Still can't figure it out. What's the problem that I'm not seeing here?

Full code:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';

const defaultPuppeteerOptions = {headless:false};
const ApolloUrl = 'https://apollo.io';
const cookies = [{
    domain: ".apollo.io",
    expirationDate: 1703861523,
    hostOnly: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    name: "__hssc",
    path: "/",
    sameSite: "lax",
    secure: false,
    session: false,
    storeId: "0",
    value: "21978340.1.1703859723",
    id: 1,
  },

]

export default async function Start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(defaultPuppeteerOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(ApolloUrl);
    await page.setCookie(cookies);
}
```

Comment: How about `const cookies = {` instead of `const cookies = [{`? It's really one cookie, not an array, hence `setCookie` rather than `setCookies`.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Works for me without the array on Puppeteer ^21.6.0/Node 18.16.1 and your exact code, with the one modification described above.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't take an array. You have to pass them one at a time:

```
page.setCookie(cookie1, cookie2)
```

or spread them

```
page.setCookie(...cookies)
```

Comment: Same error still... read the error message on the question

Comment: Some typescript error I guess, it has nothing to do with puppeteer and those cookies look fine.